# (closed)How Can I get All Versions of One File by Using pysvn

Tags: python, file, svn, revision, pysvn

Well,My boss ask me to do this:
check and find the revision of the initialization handle for a variation.

but there thousands of variations.

I can use client.diff now ,but how can i get all versions of one file ?

Comment: Would [`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) help?

Comment: revision = \
checkout( url,
          path,
          recurse=True,
          revision=pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.head ),
          peg_revision=pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.unspecified ),
          ignore_externals=False )

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the list of revision numbers? If so, use the `Client.log()` function. It will return a list of all revisions of the specified file.

```
In [48]: url='http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/README'

In [49]: log = c.log(url)

In [50]: [x.revision.number for x in log]
Out[50]: 
[1209505,
 1209499,
 1150179,
 1129808,
 739831,
 494716,
 490083,
 350202,
 106103,
 97800,
 94766,
 94066,
 92186,
 91989,
 90516,
 90357,
 90149,
 89992,
 87515,
 87481,
 87473,
 87470]
```

Or, if you need the actual contents of each of the revisions of the file, try this:

```
all_versions = { x.revision.number : c.cat(url, x.revision) for x in c.log(url) }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question .But i have got my solution.